# How to export all stories and tasks of an EPIC as CSV in RTC?

Tags: agile, export-to-csv, rational-team-concert

As per Jazz forum, only was to do this is using RTC API, but not sure how exactly this can be done. Anyone knows how to export?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the GUI: simply make a query selecting the work item you want and export them:

> Click `File > Export`.
>   Alternatively, in the Team Artifacts view, you can right-click a query and select Export Work Items.

(you also have a button on the query result GUI itself:

![https://jazz.net/forum/upfiles/exporting_defcts_IE_issue.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qLAE.jpg)

)

See:

- "[Exporting work items](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.team.workitem.doc/topics/t_exporting_work_items.html)"
- "[Guide for Importing Jazz Work Items from Bugzilla and Other Systems](https://jazz.net/library/article/69)" (about import, but illustrates export as well)

[image: https://jazz.net/library/content/techtips/rtc/2.0/importing-work-items/images/bug-export-csv.png]